# Putting a border around a column on ggheatmap

Tags: r, border, heatmap

I have been trying to put a border around a specific column of a correlation heatmap I made using ggheatmap. I want to place a border around the correlation values for the 'quality' or 7th element, but can't seem to get it to work properly. I have a similar heatmap to the one on this page http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization

```
geom_rect(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 3.5, col = "black", alpha = 0)
```

I've looked at using geom_react, but unsure how to format it so it outlines only the 'quality' element (as an example, the 3 values in the wt element from the link). I added a photo of how my heatmap looks atm.

[image: My current heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have your data or code, but we can make a similar plot using the built in `mtcars` data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)

cormat <- cor(mtcars)
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- NA

heatmap <- ggplot(reshape2::melt(cormat),
       aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2)), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('blue', 'white', 'red'), 
                       na.value = 'white') +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.4, 0.9),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal') +
  coord_equal()

heatmap
```

[image]

To draw the rectangle, we can add it using the ggplot function `annotate`

```
heatmap + 
  annotate('rect', xmin = 0.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 3.5,
           fill = NA, color = 'black', size = 1)
```

[image]